# Math assignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, texshop

I want to make the following in latex. 
[image]

I have following two questions:

1. How can I make the green boxes so I can write number of points.
2. How can I write page number as shown in the picture. So on even pages the page number appears on left above and on odd page on top right.

Here is my code:

```
%\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
%\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%
\usepackage{nicefrac} % For comparison
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\graphicspath{{Figures/}} 
\usepackage{changepage}
%\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{a4}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\graphicspath{{Figures/}} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyhead[RO, LE]{ 1b Ma 2011, RJ}
%\fancyhead[LE,CO]{Opgavesæt nr. 1}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%
%
%\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
%  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\setlength{\columnsep}{40mm}
%%\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5mm}
%%\setlength{columnsep}{20pt}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{array}% in the preamble
%%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{length}









\newcommand{\B}{{\Bbb {B}}}
\newcommand{\N}{{\Bbb {N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\Bbb {Q}}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\Bbb {R}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{{\Bbb {Z}}}
\newcommand{\SIM}{\textrm{SIM}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\Bbb {D}}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\Bbb {E}}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30mm}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5mm}
%\setlength{columnsep}{20pt}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}% in the preamble
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{length}
\newcommand\TS{\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}}
\newcommand\BS{\rule[-2.3ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{example}{Eksempel}%[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{S\ae tning}%[chapter]
%\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
%\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
%\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{opgave}[theorem]{Opgave}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
%\newtheorem*{theorem}{Sætning}
%\newtheorem*{eksperiment}{Eksperiment}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyhead[RO, LE]{ 1b Ma 2011, RJ}
%\fancyhead[LE,CO]{Opgavesæt nr. 1}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\frenchspacing

\definecolor{dartmouthgreen}{rgb}{0.05, 0.5, 0.06}
\definecolor{debianred}{rgb}{0.84, 0.04, 0.33}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
    \renewcommand\quote{\list{}{\leftmargin=1pt\rightmargin=0pt}\item[]}  {\endlist}
        \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} 
    \newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
  \gdef\@VORNE{1}
  \left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
    \begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
  \hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
  \else
    \ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
    \else\@arraycr\fi%
    #1%
    \expandafter\xvekSp@lten
  \fi}
\makeatother





\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE \textcolor{debianred}{}}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\vspace{10mm}
\textsc{\Large   \textcolor{blue}{}}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large }\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title
%\textsc{\large \textcolor{debianred}{ Kl. 08:00-13:00}}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{10mm}
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \textcolor{magenta}{ }}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%

%\textsc{\large \textcolor{dartmouthgreen}{Klassen: 1J}}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title
%\textsc{\large \textcolor{blue}{\it Rabia Jeelani}}\\[0.5cm] 

\textsc{\large \textcolor{dartmouthgreen}{\it }}\\[0.5cm] 
{\large \textcolor{blue}{{\textsc  }}}   }\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large \textcolor{dartmouthgreen}{}}\\[0.5cm]


%\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
%\begin{flushleft} \large
%\emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith} % Your name
%\end{flushleft}
%\end{minipage}
%~
%\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
%\begin{flushright} \large
%\emph{Supervisor:} \\
%Dr. James \textsc{Smith} % Supervisor's Name
%\end{flushright}
%\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%{\large \today}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\title{\textcolor{magenta}{Matematik B}\\
% \textcolor{blue}{\bf  Terminsprøve 2015%Lineær Sammenhæng:  
%}}
%\author{Rabia Jeelani
%%\\ Besvarelse
%%         \\
%            }
%\date{\today}

%
%\begin{center}
% \textcolor{blue}{\huge \bf  STX Terminsprøve}\\
% \textcolor{darkgreen}{\bf \large  Marts 2012}
%\end{center}
%
%\vspace{40mm}

%\begin{center}
% \textcolor{dunkelmagenta}{\huge \bf  Matematik(2gMa3)}\\
% \textcolor{darkYellow}{\Large \bf  B-niveau}\\
% \textcolor{Plum}{{\bf  Torsdag den 15. marts 2012}}\\
%  
%\end{center}

\begin{document}

\vspace{8mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item[{\bf Opgave 1}]  Reducér udtrykket mest muligt  $$(x+y)^2-x(x+2y)$$
\end{itemize}

\vspace{7mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item[{\bf Opgave 2}]  
Lad $\overrightarrow{a}= \Spvek{2;4t}$ og  $\overrightarrow{b}= \Spvek{-1;4}$.  

\begin{itemize}
\item[a)] Bestem $t$ så at $\overrightarrow{a}$  og $\overrightarrow{b}$ er parallelle. 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking two unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: By the way, if you specify `twoside` as an option for the `article` documentclass, the page numbers should be placed on the outer side of the page.
`\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,twoside]{article}`

Comment: Please consider cleaning up the preamble in your MWE. Several packages are loaded twice, or even more times.

Comment: Please consider also removing everything from your MWE that isn't necessary to show your problem.  There are many packages and definitions that are unrelated.